# Checkout Field Validation in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to disable checkout fields in WooCommerce from allowing characters outside of `a-z`, `0-9`, `,` `hyphens`, `full-stops`, and `commas`. A customer entered an emoji in a checkout field and it created a problem with the order report.

I have tried the following in `functions.php`. This oddly enough only disabled numbers in the first name field, despite it being allowed.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'misha_validate_fname_lname', 10, 2 );
function misha_validate_fname_lname( $fields, $errors ) {
    if ( preg_match( '/[^A-Za-z0-9,\-\.&]/', $fields['billing_first_name'] ) ) {

    } else {
        $errors->add( 'validation', __( 'Please input that correctly.' ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable checkout fields in WooCommerce from allowing any other characters than:

- A-Z
- a-z
- 0-9
- @ (I added this because you will need it for emails)
- hyphens
- full-stops
- commas

You can use the following code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_checkout_field_validation', 10, 2 );
function custom_checkout_field_validation( $data, $errors ) {
    // Make sure to replace "field_name" with the name of the field you want to validate
    if ( ! preg_match( '/^[a-zA-Z0-9@.-,]*$/', $data['field_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'validation_error', __( 'Error: Only a-z, A-Z, 0-9, @, hyphens, full-stops and commas are allowed in the field.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
}
```